# I'm trying to make a multiplication table but how can I print the output by columns side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

I got the correct output but I can't make it print the columns side by side.
How can I print as columns inside a for loop?

```
column = int(input("column: "))
Num1=1
Num2=1
Mult=0

for Num1 in range(1,10):
    for Num2 in range(1,column+1): 
        if Num1==1:
            print(1)
        else:
            Mult= Num1+Mult
            print(Mult)
    print(" ")
    Mult=0
```

A input of `3` gets me all values from 1*1 up to 9*3:

```
1
1
1

2
4
6

...

8
16
24

9
18
27
```

whereas I want them like so:

```
1   1   1
2   4   6
3   6   9
   ...
8  16  24
9  18  27
```

Comment: read the documentation of print - take care to notice the `end=""` param. or build each line and print it when done building it ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/7505395

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 0):

You can control what to put between several values (`print(1,2,3,4, sep="#"` ) using `sep="#"` and what to put at the end of the printed line with `'end='\n'`.

Changing

```
print(1, end="   ")     # some space instead of \n
```

and

```
print(Mult, end="   ")  # after each column should work
```

in combination with the loops you got should get you started (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/7505395) for more in depth explanation or review the official documentation of [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for details.

---

You can solve your task with some creative formatting, generator expressions, joining of generator decompositions in a single print statement:

```
rows_up_to_X_times = 12
columns_up_to_X = 12

max_width = len(str(rows_up_to_X_times * columns_up_to_X ))

# 99*99 max - need to adapt formatting otherwise
print(  *('  '.join((f"{b:2}*{a:2} = {a*b:{max_width}}" 
                      for a in range(1,rows_up_to_X_times+1)))
          for b in range(1,columns_up_to_X+1)), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
 1* 1 =   1   1* 2 =   2   1* 3 =   3   1* 4 =   4  [...]   1*10 =  10   1*11 =  11   1*12 =  12
 2* 1 =   2   2* 2 =   4   2* 3 =   6   2* 4 =   8  [...]   2*10 =  20   2*11 =  22   2*12 =  24
 3* 1 =   3   3* 2 =   6   3* 3 =   9   3* 4 =  12  [...]   3*10 =  30   3*11 =  33   3*12 =  36
 4* 1 =   4   4* 2 =   8   4* 3 =  12   4* 4 =  16  [...]   4*10 =  40   4*11 =  44   4*12 =  48
 5* 1 =   5   5* 2 =  10   5* 3 =  15   5* 4 =  20  [...]   5*10 =  50   5*11 =  55   5*12 =  60
 6* 1 =   6   6* 2 =  12   6* 3 =  18   6* 4 =  24  [...]   6*10 =  60   6*11 =  66   6*12 =  72
 7* 1 =   7   7* 2 =  14   7* 3 =  21   7* 4 =  28  [...]   7*10 =  70   7*11 =  77   7*12 =  84
 8* 1 =   8   8* 2 =  16   8* 3 =  24   8* 4 =  32  [...]   8*10 =  80   8*11 =  88   8*12 =  96
 9* 1 =   9   9* 2 =  18   9* 3 =  27   9* 4 =  36  [...]   9*10 =  90   9*11 =  99   9*12 = 108
10* 1 =  10  10* 2 =  20  10* 3 =  30  10* 4 =  40  [...]  10*10 = 100  10*11 = 110  10*12 = 120
11* 1 =  11  11* 2 =  22  11* 3 =  33  11* 4 =  44  [...]  11*10 = 110  11*11 = 121  11*12 = 132
12* 1 =  12  12* 2 =  24  12* 3 =  36  12* 4 =  48  [...]  12*10 = 120  12*11 = 132  12*12 = 144
```

See

- [Fancier output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)
- [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
- [Format specifying mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

for more on formatting strings with numbers etc.